# Comparar dois arrays com PHP

Tags: php, array

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto onde preciso comparar dois arrays e ir organizando os valores.

Exemplo:

```
# Objeto 1
$array1 = [1, 2, 3];
# bjeto 2
$array2 = [2, 1, 3];
```

Preciso mostrar para o usuário uma lista desse tipo:

Comparação:

```
Obj 1 | Obj 2
  1   |   2^ (maior)
  2^  |   1
  3   |   3
```

Comment: explica um pouco melhor o que exatamente voce quer retornar para o usuario, nao entendi muito bem essa lista.

Comment: Assim esta melhor ? @NeuberOliveira

Comment: Não consegui compreender o que deseja fazer com esses valores, os arrays estão desordenados e quer comparar os valores indice a indice do array? E depois quer fazer o que com o resultado? Deseja unir os 2 arrays de forma ordenada?

Comment: Veja array_intersect e array_diff no manual do PHP, pode ser que ajude..

Answer (score 1):

Acho que é isso, so precisa dar uma adaptada por que aqui estou levando em conta que um array possa ser maior do que outro, do jeito que fiz isso pode inverter os objetos.

```
$array1 = [1, 2, 3];
$array2 = [2, 1, 3, 4, 5];
$resultado = [];

//arrayG = Greater array com o maior tamanho
$arrayG = $array1;
//arrayL = Lower array com o meno tamanho
$arrayL = $array2;

//tamanho dos arrays
$array1Size = count($array1);
$array2Size = count($array2);

//isso define qual o maior array, acho mais facil para fazer o for, alem de iterar em so 1 array
if($array2Size>$array1Size){
    $arrayG = $array2;
    $arrayL = $array1;
}

echo "Objeto 1 | Objeto 2<br>";
foreach($arrayG as $i=>$v1){
    //Aqui so verifico se o valor existe no array menor
    if(isset($arrayL[$i]) ){
        $v2 = $arrayL[$i];
    }else{
        $v2 = 0;
    }

    //note que aqui eu inverti os valores que passo para a funcao
    echo getGreaterValue($v1, $v2).' | '.getGreaterValue($v2, $v1).'<br>';
}


function getGreaterValue($v1, $v2){
    return $v1.' '.($v1>$v2 ? ' ^' : '');
}
```